# AbstractUser model with custom field shows myapp.class.None

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    follows = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, blank=True, null=True)
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    likes = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    dislikes = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and the following views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import *


def index(request):
    actualUser = User.objects.all()
    for i in actualUser:
        print(i.id)
        print(i.follows)
        
    return render(request, "network/index.html")
```

but it prints this:

```
1
network.User.None
2
network.User.None
```

Need help cant reach the custom field follows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *manager* will print `ModelName.None`. You can make use of `.all()` to obtain the `QuerySet` that this manager presents:

```
def index(request):
    actualUser = User.objects.all()
    for i in actualUser:
        print(i.id)
        print(i.follows.all())
        
    return render(request, 'network/index.html')
```

You can make use of [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to prevent the *N+1 problem* and load all related objects in bulk and do the JOINing at the Django/Python level:

```
def index(request):
    actualUser = User.objects.prefetch_related('follows')
    for i in actualUser:
        print(i.id)
        print(i.follows.all())
        
    return render(request, 'network/index.html')
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot, i was following a course of django and to make a project i got stuck in this.